# How to get Chrome alert (message, etc.) when all pages loaded to use with AHK

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autohotkey

I'm using AHK to automate some of my activities. One of them is multiclicking on links on page in chrome. So, I write some script, that clicks with {MButton} on that links, and now should wait untill all opened pages finish loading. Now I'm using Sleep T to wait, but based on page heaviness it takes different time. So, it can loose some time, or start next stage before it finish loading. I find [this Control Freak answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698421/how-do-i-wait-for-google-chrome-to-load-a-webpage-before-continuing-in-autohotke), but it works only on an active page. Is there any way in Chrome to do anything to get some message to know when all pages finish loading, that I can grab with AHK as flag?

Comment: You should look into Selenium Webdriver to automate chrome.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to read about it and use it.